# EditText text alignment

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

**How can I align the text in RightCenter position 75 I hade tried Amt.setGravity(Gravity.END); and Amt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);** but it still top right aligned 
I have done

```
final EditText Amt = new EditText(this);
    Amt.setId(20);
    Amt.setText("");
    Amt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Amt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
    Amt.setHint("Amount");
    Amt.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    Amt.setSingleLine(false);
    Amt.setLines(1);
    Amt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_bg);
    Amt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    Amt.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    TourExpenseListDetailRow.addView(Amt);// add the column to the table row here
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)Amt.getLayoutParams();
    params2.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
    params2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    Amt.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

Comment: use `params2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL`

Comment: @ChorWaiChun this, since going to the layout params, will inflect on the positioning of the view inside his parent, and not the content of the view itself

Comment: @Sean the layout is only used to be set on amount edittext, so I don't think it will affect anything other than the edittext itself

Comment: @Sean er.. oh ya, my fault, should be `Amt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [center](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER) on your `Amt.setGravity(Gravity.END);`

EDIT, Like this:

```
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score -3):

in CSS is "line-height: pixel"

Comment: He was asking about Android layouts, not HTML